# Macro to copy values only from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I've this VBA code

```
Sheets("log").Range("A125:f1000").Copy _ 
Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

and it copies perfectly from sheet `log` to `data`. The only problem I'm facing is that it copies formulas with it as well whereas I only want values. I want to use same VBA code with some modifications to paste values only.

Answer (score 10):

Without using clipboard:

```
Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Sheets("log").Range("A125:f1000").Value
```

Comment: thnx for quick reply. macro is running fine but there is nothing on target sheet(data)

Comment: You should use `Sheets("data").Cells(Sheets("data").Rows.Count, "A")` because `Rows` without qualifier evaluate to ActiveSheet. I didn't changed that because you said 'copies perfectly'!

Comment: im sorry. but its not giving me error neither copying any thing.

Answer (score 2):

Need to add `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Next time try Recording a macro and modifying the code

```
Sheets("log").Range("A125:f1000").Copy
Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _ 
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: thnx mehow. but this isnt working. its showing an error. i've "Date" farmula in "log" sheet cell, which i want to copy as value only in "data" sheet so it will not change if i open file next day.

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand what you mean. This **copies values only** and **not formulas**. If you have a formula in sheet `log` it will **not** be copied as a formula into `data`. I thought that's what you have asked for. It definitely isn't giving me an error.

Comment: this is exactly what i want. but whn i run macro its does not compile and stops at this point, highlighted with yellow Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _ 
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? have you pasted the code **exactly** as I have posted it?

Comment: yes i've pasted the exact code but when i run it its stops at second line. its selecting the data from "log" sheet but not pasting it on "data".

Comment: its says.. "run time error 1004, paste special method of range class failed.

Comment: are you sheets called "log" and "data"? check spelling and case-sensitivity

Comment: okay.. i've changed sheets names as they were case-sensitive, and now its gving another error "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized"

Comment: oh, ok. this is another issue that is not related to this question. please start another question. for this one you can accept one of the answers as they have solved your original problem