# VBA: Speeding up Copying

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have two questions regarding VBA efficiency. My VBA code grabs a cell value from one sheet, places it in another excel workbook which then performs it's own calculations and returns a result, and I copy that result back into the original workbook.A simplified version of my code is:

```
dim currentWB as workbook
dim currentSheet as worksheet
dim calcWB as workbook
dim calcSheet as worksheet 
dim numRows as integer 
dim i as integer
dim target as range
dim result as range


set currentWB = workbooks.Open(...)
set currentSheet = currentWB.Sheets("sheetName")
set calcWB = workbooks.Open(...)
set calcSheet = calcWB.Sheets("sheetName")
set target = calcSheet.Cells(1,1)
set result = calcSheet.Cells(2,1)

numRows = activeSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count


For i = 0 to numRows
  target.Value = currentSheet.Cells(i,1).Value
  currentSheet.Cells(i,2) = result.Value
next i

currentWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
calcWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

In the actual script, we're copying over not one like above, but 13. The loop goes through ~ 15,000 records. Right now, I'm averaging 1.5 seconds per loop.

The two questions I have are:

1. Should I be naming and setting these ranges, i.e.:

   dim target as range
   set target = calcSheet.Cells(1,1)
   target.Value = currentSheet.Cells(i,1).Value

Instead of

calcSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = currentSheet.Cells(i,1).Value

2. Is there a better way to do the copy of several non sequential cells from one sheet to another, i.e.

Instead of

```
    curSheet.Cells(i, 1) = someRange.Value
    curSheet.Cells(i, 2) = someRange2.Value
    curSheet.Cells(i, 3) = someRange3.Value

    ...

    curSheet.Cells(i, 14) = someRange14.Value
    curSheet.Cells(i, 15) = someRange15.Value
    curSheet.Cells(i, 16) = someRange16.Value
```

Something quicker?

Thank you all so much!

With gratitude,
Zac

**This code took 66 seconds to run 50 records (compare with solutions below)

Comment: You may have simplified your copying step a little too much. However, if you're copying multiple cells over to perform a calculation then it might be better to 1) copy all the values in one shot or 2) suspend calculation (set to manual) while you copy over the values, then manually calculate the `calcSheet` before copying back the result (otherwise Excel will try to recalculate for each cell you copy over)

Comment: The best way to handle this is to move the calculations into VBA and just have input and result cells that get filled by VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams, that might be the way to go. ja72, I would love to move the calculations into VBA - but unfortunately there is some corporate politics at play here. The calcsheet, as of now, is untouchable, which is the reason I have to do this whole hack to begin with.

Comment: Ahhh the wisdom of middle managment. Maybe a future http://www.thedailywtf.com/ article (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy many values at once then use a direct assignment

```
currentSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numRows,1).Value = otherSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numRows,1).Value
```

The `.Range()` property convers a single cell into a range of cells with the given dimensions and all their values can be assigned or copied.

Comment: This is how I originally had it (before Dim'ing ranges). I read that it is costly to use both the .Cells() and .Range() methods as it forces VBA to calculate the cell each time - whereas Dim'ing them pulls a direct reference to the cell (and only the single calculation at the Dim). Is this incorrect?

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: As you can see I did not use `Cell()`. I only use `Range()`. Also there is no re-calculation because all you are storing is values.

Comment: I'm looking up the performance differences between .cells() vs .range() and I'm getting a lot of hits saying that .cells is quicker (if you're referencing a single cell - of course if it's a whole range, you must use range. But as I pointed out in my question, the cells I need are non-sequential, so I have to pick them up individually). See here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Q_20808898.html, http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/lounge-v-2-0/258950-cells-1-1-vs-range-a1.html... Maybe you've found something different that I missed?

Comment: You are stuck between a rock and a hard place. You cannot alter the structure of the sheets (to make value access sequential via an intermediate worksheet) and you cannot move the calculations into VBA.

Comment: So you're saying that I'm pretty much doomed to ~2 seconds a record for ~15,000 records? I might try turning off/on the autocalc (obviously it has to be on for calcsheet to work), but it doesn't need to be on while copying the data. I don't think that should really make any difference, however, since any time I'm making an alteration to the workbook, I'll want it to calculate..

Comment: Did your comment originally include the mention of using an intermediary sheet? I dont remember that there, but that's exactly what @MaciejLos wrote below. I cant modify existing sheets in calcWB, but i can add a cover sheet that pulls the values into a sequential range. It's a very simple and hopefully effective solution. I'm going to try doing that and then test which method, .range() or copy-dest, is actually quicker and mark the answer based on that. Thanks man for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use:

```
SourceRange.Copy DestinationRange
```

Please, see: [Range.Copy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I looked into that method, but couldn't find anywhere saying that this method is quicker that .value = .value. Maybe you found something I missed? Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Try to loop over the 15,000 records. How long it takes the time? Then try to use Copy method on entire range, not single row, cell.

Comment: That would work, if it was a sequential range. my values are scattered all over the sheet (and no, I cannot change that - even though i'd like to.) However, maybe I can create another sheet that pulls all of the values into a single range? hmm...

Comment: I looked at your code again and it sounds like you have sequential data. Nevertheless... the most interesting is that, that you copy data into another sheet to make some calculations and get back the result into original workbook. I think you need to seek a possibility to workaround it...

Comment: I guess what i meant by sequential is that the cells themselves were next to each other without interruption. This isn't the case. However, you may be right that i should create a sheet in calcWorkbook that simply pulls all the necessary points into a sequential range. The added sheet shouldn't tax performance too much and the switch to a single range copy call (instead of 13) might be really beneficial. Let me try that. If that works, i'll test the copy-destination method and mark your answer right. Thanks man!

Comment: The copy method was indeed much quicker, but for some reason it wasn't copying over values.. My destination sheet was blank. I saw one SO answer mention the destination.pastespecial xlPastValues method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565456/macro-to-copy-values-only-from-one-sheet-to-another), but this didn't solve it either.. hmm. Either way, I'm sure I was just doing something wrong. Your solution was much better than my original code. Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

If the target range is contiguous, you can go this way:

```
    curSheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1,16).Value = Array(someRange.Value, someRange2.Value, _
                                              someRange3.Value, [...], someRange16.Value)
```